# Running Gitlab Docker Container on port 80 ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: docker, ssl, gitlab, containers, podman

I'm beyond confused as to why I'm getting an error 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' when I try running a Gitlab docker container on port 80, but if I change the port number to 8000, it totally works.

I've scoured the internet for four days looking for answers, but the only thing I've seen suggested is the container is missing an SSL cert for the domain name.  However, the container works just fine if I switch the port to 8000.  Can anyone please liberate me from this frustration and explain why 8000 is OK and 80 is not?

**Code that doesn't work:**

```
sudo podman run --detach \
--name gitlab-ce \
--hostname gitlab.example.com \
--publish 443:443 \
--publish 80:80 \
--publish 8022:22 \
--restart always \
--volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab:Z \
--volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab:Z \
--volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab:Z \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

**Code that does work:**

```
sudo podman run --detach \
--name gitlab-ce \
--hostname gitlab.example.com \
--publish 443:443 \
--publish 8000:80 \
--publish 8022:22 \
--restart always \
--volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab:Z \
--volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab:Z \
--volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab:Z \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

It's the same exact code, the only difference is the one port number.

Answer (score 2):

Well, apparently the answer to this question is patience.  For some reason, when on port 8000 it only took about 2 minutes for the server to prepare itself.  When using port 80, it took over 10 minutes to prepare itself.  Not exactly sure why that is, but it's working now.  So frustrating.  I had blown away the container because it wasn't working fast enough, then tried again.

I find most of my questions on here to be answered the same way.  Patience.

Comment: LOL, made my day - _Can anyone please liberate me from this frustration and explain why..._  and _I find most of my questions on here to be answered the same way. Patience._